# user input minus database

Tags: c#, database, user-input

I am trying to learn how to make calculations by using the user input subtracting with the amount provided in the database. That amount is under of a specific name. Basically (input) - (data from database)

What i know is i have to take out the data first. So my code is:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table Where username=" + username;
```

then make calculation and put the new data into the database. This could be done by using the UPDATE.

example,

```
"UPDATE Table SET amount='" + amount + "'WHERE username='" + userName + "'";
```

But i have trouble in making the calculations. The amount wont reduced.

In my recent researched i should make:

```
int newAmount = nowAmount - amount
```

??? Unsuccessful by the way.

Update info: im using a webservice just incase if you are wondering

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `newAmount` in your update statement, not `amount`, yes?

Comment: +1 for Goose's suggestion. Also, try to avoid SQL-injection, concatenating queries with user input is usually a bad idea.

Comment: something off topic but be aware of sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simple enough to be written in just a few moments.

First you get the input from the user from the form or what so ever the medium. For example:

```
int userInput = Request.Form["some_input_name"];
```

And then get the data from the Database:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table Where username=" + username;
```

Now, you need to select the column otherwise you'll get an Exception. Try this:

```
int dbValue = "";
foreach (var row in variable_of_database) {
  dbValue = row.amount;
}
```

Now, just subtract it.

```
int newValue = userInput - dbValue;
```

Then the same `UPDATE` method.

There is a typo in your code:

```
"UPDATE Table SET amount='" + amount + "'WHERE username='" + userName + "'";
                           //  ^^^ You sure?
```

Try updating it to the new variable name i.e. `newValue`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using webservice. Will there be any difference?

Comment: @user3438429, nope ... there won't be any...